# Secure login php

Tags: php

I am doing, a webpage that the users will introduce their credit cards and also they could get virtual money.

But i was thinking if the next type of login will be secure. For everything SQL INJECTION. And hack.

- It will be encrypted with SSL
- Paswoord md5.
- Mail will be validate with js

Login Proces Which its better?:
First one:
- SELECT * FROM users WHERE pass='$pass'
- and the users selected i compare it with the users or mail from the username.

Second one:
- SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='$user'
- Pass selected compare it with the pass from user

Thrird one:
- Hash md5 both user and password and compare it directly in the DB. But I need to save the username encrypted and normal

Thanks :)

Comment: SSL good for anti-packet-sniffing but with cain can be spoofed/forged, md5 was never meant for encrypting passwords, validating with js is useless, you should always validate server-side, there is no need to digest/secure usernames

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Mail will be validate with js"?

Comment: That its a real Mail address with a@a.com.etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Thrird one: - Hash md5 both user and password and compare it directly in the DB. But I need to save the username encrypted and normal"

This one seems ok. You don't necessarily need to save the username in both formats. In the DB use MD5 encryption which is one way. In the application (PHP), encrypt the username using some 2 way encryption and save this in the session. When you need to get your user information, simply decrypt the encrypted username in php, send the query to the database encrypting the plain text username with md5 again.

N.B. I dont know how secure you need your site, but I believe MD5 was cracked already.. dont know for sure.

Comment: Yes md5 was cracked that´s why i will use sha1. About your answer you said i could decrypt the username. But i want 1 way encrypt. Also this could eliminate sql injection

Comment: What I suggested uses 2 way encryption for the username stored in the session only. The Database uses 1 way encryption e.g. MD5. I don't see any other way of doing it other than storing the username as plaintext in the session. That's why I think 2 way encryption for the username is the better choice for the session only.

Comment: Nice idea. And that will eliminate sql injection. Because the e-mail isn't to secret

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the second option as many users can have the same password making the first option less efficient.

You should know that md5 is now broken. I would use sha1 encryption and salt the passwords. I don't think there's any reason to encrypt the usernames, but I could be wrong.

Comment: OH i don't know that md5 was broken. Then i will check sha1. Thanks

Comment: Maybe creating a new encryption its possible?

Comment: you don't have to create a new algorithm. you just need to make sure to use best practices and salt your passwords. do all validation server side and make sure your scripts are away from prying eyes. don't be too paranoid about the matter, just make sure you do your research thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

For properly hashing passwords, you need to salt them and use a decent hashing algorithm. Avoid reinventing the wheel here and go with an existing, proven implementation like [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/). The author also has a handful of great articles about password hashing and how to use the library.

Comment: But if its public. Someone could learn it and know how to crack it. I really need to be really secure the webpage. Almost like a bank

Comment: @Ernesto Security through obscurity is no security! A system is secure because it is logically sound, not because the algorithm is unknown. In any good security system, the *implementation* does not matter. Thinking you can create a cryptographically sound system by yourself without having it peer-reviewed is a big mistake.

Comment: I never think it like that. I will check the webpage that you send me. thank you. And sorry what do you mean with salt them?

Comment: @Ernesto You have a lot to learn, young jedi. ;-P Read the [introductory article](http://www.openwall.com/articles/PHP-Users-Passwords).

Comment: I investigate and see whats salt. I think i have an idea to create a secure login. I will create it and post it. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

This is a stripped down secure login function I built and ive used on many of my projects.
It shows that it is not just about checking username and password, hash's can be made that are updated and checked along with your username.

Have a look through it and your kinda get the idea.

```
<?php 
session_start();

//Checks on all pages, this checks time validity & hased user ip set at login, it will log out if something changes
$_SESSION['user_status'] = auth($_SESSION['user_name'],$_SESSION['user_hash'],"","","check");
//or
if(@auth($_SESSION['user_name'],$_SESSION['user_hash'],"","","check")=="LOGGED_IN" && $_SESSION['user_status']=='LOGGED_IN'){
    //Logged _in
}

//LOGIN
if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])){
    $_SESSION['user_status'] = auth("","",$_POST['user'],$_POST['pass'],"login");
}

//LOGOUT USER
if(isset($_REQUEST['do']) && $_REQUEST['do'] =='logout'){
    auth("","","","","logout");
    header('Location: ./index.php');
}

/**
         * Auth function for logging in & persistaint user checks
         *
         * @param $_SESSION string $logged_in_user
         * @param $_SESSION string $hash
         * @param $_POST string $username
         * @param $_POST string $password
         * @param string $exe
         * @return set $_SESSION string
         */
function auth($logged_in_user,$hash,$username="",$password="",$exe) {
    global $db;
    if ($exe=='login') {
        //LOGIN
        $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username="'.mysql_real_escape_string($username).'" and password="'.mysql_real_escape_string(sha1($password)).'"',$db);
        $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($num=='1') {
            session_regenerate_id();
            $_SESSION['logged_in']=true;
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
                $_SESSION['user_name'] = $row['username'];
                $_SESSION['user_hash'] = sha1($row['username'].$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
                $_SESSION['user_ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                $_SESSION['user_date'] = time();
                $_SESSION['user_level'] = $row['user_level']; // have different user levels for your users
            }
            mysql_query('REPLACE INTO users values ("'.mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_id']).'","'.mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_name']).'","'.mysql_real_escape_string(sha1($password)).'","'.mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_hash']).'","'.mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_ip']).'","'.mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_date']).'","'.mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_comment']).'","'.mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_level']).'")',$db);
            $return = 'LOGGED_IN';
            return $return;
        }elseif($num >='2') {
            $_SESSION['logged_in']=false;
            $error = 'ERROR:MULTI:USERS';
            return $error;
        }else{
            unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
            unset($_SESSION['user_name']);
            unset($_SESSION['user_hash']);
            unset($_SESSION['user_ip']);
            unset($_SESSION['user_date']);
            unset($_SESSION['user_level']);
            $_SESSION['logged_in']=false;
            session_destroy();
            $return = 'ACCESS_DENIDE';
            return $return;
        }
        return $return;
    }
    if($exe=='check') {
        //CHECK
        $result = mysql_query('SELECT hash,ip,user_date FROM users WHERE username="'.mysql_real_escape_string($logged_in_user).'" and hash="'.mysql_real_escape_string($hash).'"',$db);
        if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1) {
            $rows = mysql_fetch_row($result);
            $timeout = (time()-1800);
            if($rows[2]<=$timeout){auth("","","","","logout");
            return'ACCESS_TIMEOUT';
            }
            if($hash==$rows[0] && $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']==$rows[1]) {
                $return = 'LOGGED_IN';
                mysql_query('UPDATE users set user_date="'.time().'"',$db);
                return $return;
            }else {
                session_regenerate_id();
                $_SESSION['logged_in'] = 'ACCESS_DENIDE';
                $return = 'ACCESS_DENIDE';
                return $return;
            }
        }else{
            session_regenerate_id();
            $_SESSION['logged_in']=false;
            $return = 'ACCESS_DENIDE';
            return $return;
        }
    }
    if($exe=='logout') {
        //LOGOUT
        unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
        unset($_SESSION['user_name']);
        unset($_SESSION['user_hash']);
        unset($_SESSION['user_ip']);
        unset($_SESSION['user_date']);
        unset($_SESSION['user_level']);
        unset($_SESSION['logged_in']);
        session_destroy();
        session_regenerate_id();
        $return = 'ACCESS_LOGGED_OUT';
        return $return;
    }
    return false;
}
?>
```